# How to get full text even after clicking on link to expand text using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape reviews from tripadvisor website. Reviews which have longer text are shown partially with 'More' link. I have used selenium to hit 'More' link and it's working but I am again getting half reviews in my final output file.

I figured out that full reviews are stored in different class but how can I access different class?

Please see a part of my code below:

```
driver.get(full_url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.moreLink").click()
r = requests.get(full_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
#soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
page_count = int(soup.select('.pagination a')[-1].text.strip())
page_results = soup.find_all("p", {"class" : "partial_entry"})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `requests.get(full_url).content` you are getting the raw markup of the page. This has nothing to do with the state the `driver` is in (notice how the `get` call is neither passed the `driver` nor run *on* the `driver`). It's in a very real sense like opening a web site in Firefox and then running `curl` to get the content - the two have no idea about each other.

What you need to do is ask **`driver`** what the markup is currently like, for example using `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span").text`.

Comment: You need to figure out which CSS selector actually matches the content after clicking the URL. `span` was just an example.